# Can i get facebook friend list without login on facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am useing facebook sdk and  getting list of my friend   but   its getting  when i login   or i need to update  url   can i get list   without need of login   my sample  code is this

```
<?php  include('src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/vikas.gautam.332/friends');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


$vikas = $facebook->api('/vikas.gautam.332');
if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>

    <?php endif ?>



<?php if ($user){?>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">   
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); 
      ?></pre>
    <?php }?>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/vikas.gautam.332/picture">
    <?php echo $vikas['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot get any data without access token and to get access token you need to login. Therefore, you still need to login. In short, it is not possible.

---

This is from [Access Tokens - Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

> An access token is a random string that identifies a User, App or Page
>   session and provides information about granted permissions. Access
>   tokens are obtained via a number of methods, each of which are covered
>   later in this document. The token also includes information about when
>   the token will expire and which app generated the token. Because of
>   privacy checks, the majority of API calls on Facebook need to include
>   an access token. There are different types of access tokens to support
>   these various cases:
>
> - User Access Token – This kind of access token is needed anytime the
>     app calls an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook
>     data (their profile, photos etc.). This can be thought of as a limited
>     and time bound permission that someone grants the app. In essence it
>     is a temporary password that the app can use on behalf of the person.
>     **User access tokens are generally obtained via a login dialog and
>     require a person to permit your app to obtain one**.

Comment: ok thanks for responce   can i get any written  article  on developer.facebook  about this sorry but i  searched and i need to show proof

Comment: one more thing that i am useing my application id so can i get friend list of  every loged in user by facebook other then me who logged in on my site by facebook

Comment: @Vickey, I have added the reference.